# Problems with checking values diagonal of other values in a matrix. (Python)

Tags: python

So my friend and I were trying to recreate Conway's game of life in python, but ran into a problem trying to check for diagonally neighboring values in our cell matrix. Our code looks for values diagonal to the value in question but for some reason it can't seem to find them. For example, a cell with 3 neighboring cells (2 adjacent, and 1 diagonal) would return as 2 neighbors.
The in order to debug we have it list the coridinates of all living cells and its neighbor count.
Here is our code:

```
initial_frame = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

next_frame = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

row = []

neighborcount = 0

next_frame = initial_frame

while True:

    for e in range(1, 10):

        for a in range(1, 10):

            row.append(initial_frame[e][a])

        print(row)

        row = []

    print("\n\n\n\n")

    input()

    for i in range(1, 10):

        for o in range(1, 10):

            neighborcount = 0

            #Down 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][i] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][i] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Right 1

            if initial_frame[o][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Left 1

            if initial_frame[o][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Down 1, Right 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Down 1, Left 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1, Left 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1, Right 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #If dead cell has exactly 3 neighbors, set it to be born

            if initial_frame[o][i] == 0 and neighborcount == 3:

                next_frame[o][i] = 1



            #If living cell:

            if initial_frame[o][i] == 1:

                #does not have either 2 or 3 neighbors, set it to die

                if neighborcount != 2 and neighborcount != 3:

                    next_frame[o][i] = 0

                print(str(o) + ", " + str(i) + ": " + str(neighborcount))

            #reset neighbors

            neighborcount = 0

    #Project set values onto real board

    initial_frame = next_frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, in this line

`next_frame = initial_frame`

Python does not actually copy the entire array. `next_frame` just starts to reference whatever `initial_frame` was referencing, so `next_frame is initial_frame` would return true.

This can be solved by exchanging the arrays at the end of the generation calculation. Like this:

```
@@ -30,8 +30,6 @@ row = []

neighborcount = 0

-next_frame = initial_frame
-
while True:

    for e in range(1, 10):
@@ -120,6 +118,8 @@ while True:

            #If dead cell has exactly 3 neighbors, set it to be born

+            next_frame[o][i] = initial_frame[o][i]
+
            if initial_frame[o][i] == 0 and neighborcount == 3:

                next_frame[o][i] = 1
@@ -143,5 +143,6 @@ while True:
            neighborcount = 0

    #Project set values onto real board
-
+    garbage_arr = initial_frame
    initial_frame = next_frame
+    next_frame = garbage_arr
```

Resulting code:

```
initial_frame = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

next_frame = [
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

row = []

neighborcount = 0

while True:

    for e in range(1, 10):

        for a in range(1, 10):

            row.append(initial_frame[e][a])

        print(row)

        row = []

    print("\n\n\n\n")

    input()

    for i in range(1, 10):

        for o in range(1, 10):

            neighborcount = 0

            #Down 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][i] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][i] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Right 1

            if initial_frame[o][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Left 1

            if initial_frame[o][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Down 1, Right 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Down 1, Left 1

            if initial_frame[(o + 1)][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1, Left 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][(i - 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #Up 1, Right 1

            if initial_frame[(o - 1)][(i + 1)] == 1:

                neighborcount += 1



            #If dead cell has exactly 3 neighbors, set it to be born

            next_frame[o][i] = initial_frame[o][i]

            if initial_frame[o][i] == 0 and neighborcount == 3:

                next_frame[o][i] = 1



            #If living cell:

            if initial_frame[o][i] == 1:

                #does not have either 2 or 3 neighbors, set it to die

                if neighborcount != 2 and neighborcount != 3:

                    next_frame[o][i] = 0

                print(str(o) + ", " + str(i) + ": " + str(neighborcount))

            #reset neighbors

            neighborcount = 0

    #Project set values onto real board
    garbage_arr = initial_frame
    initial_frame = next_frame
    next_frame = garbage_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid issues with neighbour coordinates reaching edges is to pad your matrix with a row and column of zeroes on each side.  This lets you use a list of offset to access the 8 neighbouring values without any boundary checking.

[EDIT] I just noticed that you had already padded your matrix. (I adjusted my example accordingly).  Seems that one of the issue is that you are using  range(1,10) which will only go through 1..9 but you need to go through 1..10 so they should be range(1,11)

For example:

```
next_Frame  = [ line.copy() for line in initial_frame ]
offsets     = [ (-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1) ]
for row in range(1,11):
    for col in range(1,11):
        neighbors = sum([ initial_frame[row+r][col+c] for r,c in offsets ])
        if next_Frame[row][col] == 0 and neighbors == 3:
            next_Frame[row][col] = 1 
        elif next_Frame[row][col] == 1 and neighbors not in [2,3] 
            next_Frame[row][col] = 0
```

Comment: This is an issue, but this is not THE issue.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that Python lists are actually objects so next_frame = initial_frame does not make a new copy but merely a new reference the same data.  (updated my example to make an actual copy)